# Is it possible to get parent property from child when create parent and child inline?

Tags: c#

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent() 
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var parent = new Parent()
{
    Id = 1,
    Children = new List<Child>() 
    {
        new Child()
        {
            Id = 100,
            ParentId = parent.Id
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: No, the assignment `var parent =` will be the *last* operation, so in `ParentId = parent.Id` `parent` will be *undefined*

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. Why not simply extract the parent Id to the variable?

```
var parentId = 1;
var parent = new Parent()
{
    Id = parentId,
    Children = new List<Child>() 
    {
        new Child()
        {
            Id = 100,
            ParentId = parentId
        }
    }
};
```